# Difference between publish and schema compare

Tags: visual-studio, database-project

I'm setting up database projects in Visual Studio for our existing databases and I wonder what the difference is between Schema Compare and Publish. For me **Publish** is a familiar term from using Visual Studio to develop web apis, desktop apps etc, but as it seems it would be possible to achieve the same functionality using **Schema Compare** I wonder why they are two implemented as separate things in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a schema compare, you can more easily import changes from the database into your project or manually pick/choose what you want to compare. Useful for when you need to cherry-pick items from one side or another - or even compare two databases/dacpacs that aren't in a project at all.

Publish is designed to take the state of your project, compare that to a database, and push those changes.  The Publish functionality includes the schema comparison portion, but then just picks up all differences and acts on them. It can also run the Pre/Post deploy scripts you have set up, which a Schema Compare doesn't do.

Comment: Thanks Peter! Would you personally recommend using Visual Studio database projects, or would you recommend another solution? I know that the database projects have been around for some ten years but as I never used them before I've gotten the feeling that they haven't took off. I have used RoundHousE before but I thought that I sometime ought to give the database projects a go. Do you know if they implement new features and fix bugs in the database project part of VS?

Comment: It depends. :) They have their uses, but can also have drawbacks if you have multi-db dependencies or need to handle data migrations/manipulations along the way. I have a series of articles on it from a while back, but still largely relevant. https://schottsql.com/all-ssdt-articles/    As for new features, it depends on how new or used they are. Most are implemented, but some features like Temporal tables may not be supported well.

Comment: Thanks for you input!